# In Django QuerySet, how do I return the ManyToManyField of more than one row?

Tags: django

The problem is best explained by example, consider the following two models:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Toppping)
```

My data looks like the following:

Pizza and Topping tables joined:

```
NAME        TOPPINGS
--------------------
deluxe      topping_1, topping_2
deluxe      topping_3, topping_4
hawaiian    topping_1
```

I want to get the toppings of all Pizza with name `deluxe`.  Any ideas what kind of QuerySet I have to write to get that kind of result?  The expected output for the above will be:

```
[topping_1, topping_2, topping_3, topping_4]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Topping.objects.filter(pizza__name='deluxe')
```